# Passing href link to php form

Tags: php, html

I've got a small form where I store information regarding some user choices. I'm not sure though how I can pass href links that are different for each user.

Here is a small example of the code:

```
<form method="post" action="save.php" class="form">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkthing" value="g1">
        <label>Option 1</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkthing" value="g2">
        <label>Option 2</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkthing" value="e1">
        <label>Option 3</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkthing" value="e2">
        <label>Option 4</label>
    </fieldset>

    <a data-column="1" href="link here" style="color: green;">Text</a> <br>
    <a data-column="2" href="link here">Text</a> <br>
    <a data-column="3" href="link here" style="color: green;">Text</a> <br>
    <a data-column="4" href="link here">Text</a> <br>

    <button type="submit" name="save">
      <i class="ft-check"></i> Save
    </button>
</form>
```

When href got a style, it means that is customized for the user. What I want is to store the data-column ID for that user but I am not sure how I can achieve that through PHP.

So for the above example I would store the checked checkboxes + data-column 1 + 3.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a hidden form element with javascript like this, and pull it off when the form is submitted as `$_POST['style_ele']`

```
$("form.form").find("a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("style")!==undefined){
        $("form.form").append("<input type='hidden' name='style_ele[]' value='"+$(this).data('column')+"'/>");
    }
});
```

But, if you are generating that style attribute from server-side code like php, you could just create additional hidden input along with the `a` tag

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I like that solution but I can't make it work hmm